# query/shred large xml document into sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm looking to query an xml file that's in excess of 80GB (and insert the results into a pre-existing db). This prevents me from simply declaring it as an xml variable and using openrowset. I am NOT looking to use a CLR and would prefer an entirely TSQL approach if possible (looking to do this on SQL Server 2012/Windows Server 2008)

With the 2Gb limit on the XML datatype, I realize the obvious approach is to split the file into say 1GB pieces. However, it would simply be too messy to be worthwhile (Elements in the document are of varying sizes and not all elements have the same sub-elements. Only looking to keep some common elements though).

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: sorry for being stupid but have you tried OPENROWSET BULK or BCP XML in sql server

Comment: with the length of some of the columns and the messy schema, i've found format files more trouble than their worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a simple schema (sorry, should have mentioned it) bulk cmds would probably have been the way to go. With something more messy, and given the size of the file, a SAX parser seems to provide a better solution. Reads the file without putting it into memory, I can pick out only the elements I want and not have to worry about the schema at all.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a one off thing I would use the SQL Import/Export tool. If its something that will need to be scheduled create an Integration Services package.